# Arduino Uno versus Arduino Nano power consumption

Tags: power, arduino-nano

I have both an Arduino Uno and an Arduino Nano but I can't decide which one to use for my project. My aim is to maximize battery lifetime. I have also implemented an 8-second watchdog timer to periodically sleep and wake up the ATMega328P.

- Option 1: Arduino Uno R3 + DHT11 sensor: The board is powered on by 4 * 1.25V (2700 mAh) Nickel Metal Hydride batteries and the 3.3V output voltage of the Arduino is supplied to VCC of DHT11. (**Arduino Uno specification** DC Current per I/O Pin 40 mA, DC Current for 3.3V Pin 50 mA).
- Option 2: Arduino Nano + DHT11 sensor. The board is powered on by 4 * 1.25V (2700 mAh) Nickel Metal Hydride batteries and the 3.3V output voltage of the Arduino is supplied to VCC of DHT11. (**Arduino Nano specification**: DC Current per I/O Pin: 40 mA but **NO** information for DC current for 3.3V or 5V).

I would like to know which one will be more power-efficient.

Comment: DHT11 can work from 5V. Why did you choose 3.3V?

Comment: DHT11 works for both. What difference it makes if 5V is used?

Comment: Voltage regulator at 3.3 volts dissipates part of the energy. What battery lifetime do you have? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Both these boards draw a lot of extra current due to LEDs, regulators, etc. An alternative solution is to simply turn the board on/off: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266716/power-off-arduino-via-software

Comment: I am currently using Arduino Uno and running overnight successfully. With 2700 mAh batteries, I expect will last more than 3 days but I found in many forums sleeping only ATmega328p with watchdog timer of 8s  will not  save much power. How much do you think battery life time will be? So let's say I power using only battery and deploy in a place where NO power mains is available, it is going to last only 3 to 4 days?? This is a MAJOR issue I am facing.

Comment: Please add  code and wiring diagram.

Comment: Related: [Are there good batteries to power on Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48092/are-there-good-batteries-to-power-on-arduino) by same person.

Answer (score 12):

A Uno which isn't doing anything useful except being turned on will use about 50 mA of current from the power jack at 9V.

If you use 3 x alkaline AA batteries (giving a nominal voltage of 4.5V) directly into the 5V pin of the Arduino then you might get 2500 mAh which would be 50 hours at 50 mA per hour.

You can save a considerable amount of power by using sleep modes as I describe on [my page about power](http://www.gammon.com.au/power). It also helps to use a bare processor (no voltage regulator, no LEDs).

I made a [temperature and humidity sensor](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12106) which runs from 3 x AA batteries. Using sleep mode, plus various other techniques, that is running for **over a year** without needing new batteries.

---

> I would like to know which one will be power efficient?

Both the Uno and the Nano use the same Atmega328P processor. Thus the technical considerations would be the same. Both have a voltage regulator and a "power on" LED which alone would use a lot of current, compared to everything else.

---

It's *not that hard* to make a minimal board. I have a [page about doing that](http://www.gammon.com.au/breadboard). Example of all you need:

[image: Minimal Arduino]

---

If you use a deep sleep mode, combined with using the watchdog timer to wake every 8 seconds (and check the time, say every 10 times it wakes) you can reduce power consumption right down.

My temperature sensor uses an average of 42 µA which is a **lot** less than 50 mA. (A thousand times less). Thus your 50 hours run time becomes 50,000 hours which is 2083 days. Your batteries will probably self-discharge sooner. :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Just a quick question: how do we supply 3.3 v or 5 v to temperature sensor because we will remove the voltage regulator from the chip? Can we use ftdi adapter which gives 3.3v or 5v output?

Comment: In that case will FTDI adapter too NOT consume current?

Comment: Well, if you are powering the processor you can power the temperature sensor, can't you? Did you read my page about my temperature sensor?

Comment: Yes. I read it. It seems you are powering the processor and temperature sensor sensor with FTDI? Correct me if I am wrong. My question is: does FTDI not pull the current from battery like voltage regulator of other arduino boards do?I agree we can get rid of led power consumption.

Comment: No, I am powering them from a battery. The FTDI connection is just for reprogramming it.

Comment: You are powering from 3.3 V regulated  battery?

Comment: You said you read my article about the sensor. The [schematic](http://gammon.com.au/images/Arduino/HHS_Temperature_Logger1.png) is there. It is powered by 3 x 1.5V Alkaline batteries. There is no voltage regulator. It is marked as 5V on the top left-hand corner of the schematic, but would actually be closer to 4.5V (which is what 3 x 1.5 is). It is quite acceptable to run the processor at 4.5V. If you run at 8 MHz, as I did, then 3V (1V each from 3 batteries) is still OK, as might be expected towards the end of the battery life.

Comment: If needed the power LED can just be unsoldered right?

Comment: From the Uno board? Yes, but the voltage regulator still takes some power to run.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use either use something with no USB, regulator - e.g. Pro Mini (run from 3.3V)

Just running the Arduino (or indeed most digital circuitry) from a lower voltage will already reduce power consumption - admittedly at a slight cost in processor speed. The Atmega328P will run at 12MHz on 3.3V, although the Pro Mini uses the more conservative 8MHz.

Comment: I thought of using pro mini but I found that I have to work on making circuit as pro mini is not much user friendly (in terms of loading code etc) than Arduino nano and uno. Also pro mini does not give output voltage 3.3V or 5V which can be supplied to DHT11 vcc pin easily. So

Comment: I found more work to be done from HW side. I am not good at HW making as my background is programming only.

Comment: Can we supply Vcc of pro mini to DHT11 vcc?

Comment: yes, run it all from 3.3v, using a dc-dc buck (smps) to get 3.3v instead of an LDO

Comment: @JyotiRajSharma You miss my point - run the Pro Mini from 3.3V, and use the same source to run your peripherals, avoiding any lossy linear regulators. It really isn't that hard to use a USB-serial dongle to program (which is done when connected to computer) rather than a power hogging on-board converter you aren't using.